# Malloc vs new in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, new-operator, allocation

I am transitioning from C to C++. In C++, is there any use for the `malloc` function, or can I just use the `new` keyword? For example:

```cpp
class Node {
    /* ... */
};

/* ... */

Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
// vs
Node *node = new Node;
```

Which one should I use?

Comment: Note that in C++ there is no implicit cast from void*, so on the malloc case you need to actually do `Node *node1 = reinterpret_cast<Node*>(malloc(sizeof(Node));` which is clearly too much typing.  :)  (Ok ok you can do a C-style cast too, but then why are you coding in C++?  :) )

Comment: Try not to apply C to C++ too much, they are different languages with things done in different ways.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `new`. You shouldn't need to use `malloc` in a C++ program, unless it is interacting with some C code or you have some reason to manage memory in a special way.

Your example of `node = malloc(sizeof(Node))` is a bad idea, because the constructor of `Node` (if any exists) would not be called, and a subsequent `delete node;` would have undefined results.

If you need a buffer of bytes, rather than an object, you'll generally want to do something like this:

```cpp
char *buffer = new char[1024];
// or preferably:
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(1024);
// or alternatively:
std::vector<char> buffer(1024);
```

Note that for the latter examples (using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)), there is no need to `delete` the object; its memory will automatically be freed when it goes out of scope. You should strive to avoid both `new` and `malloc` in C++ programs, instead using objects that automatically manage their own memory.

Here are your options and their benefits:

| Method | Dynamically Sized | Automatically Managed | Resizable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [`std::array<char, N>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) | No | Yes | No |
| [`new char[N]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) | Yes | No | No |
| [`std::unique_ptr<char[]>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) | Yes | Yes | No |
| [`std::vector<char>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) | Yes | Yes | Yes |

Comment: You might also use `malloc` if you are doing custom memory allocation via your own `operator::new`.

Comment: And remember that new throws a std::bad_alloc exception on failure unless call with the nothrow modifier!

Comment: Should perhaps add that new is type safe, while the return from malloc is void*.

Answer (score 9):

The direct equivalent of `malloc()` in C++ is `operator new()` which also allocates raw memory, however in most cases a `new` expression is what you want. A `new` expression both allocates an appropriate amount of raw memory and initializes an object in that memory location, returning a correctly typed pointer to the new object.

In your case , `new Node` is correct as it allocates memory and initializes a new `Node` object. Simply calling `malloc` and casting result to a pointer to `Node` won't correctly construct the `Node` object. This is critical if `Node` is not a POD-struct (e.g. when it or one of its sub-objects has a constructor that should be called).

You should avoid dynamic allocation where it is not needed; where it is needed, it is often best to initialize some sort of smart pointer with the address of the dynamically allocated object so that it's not possible to 'forget' to `delete` the obejct.

Answer (score 3):

One of the primary differences between `new` and `malloc` is that `new` will call the object's constructor.

Another difference is that `new` will throw an exception (may be circumvented by a compiler `pragma`) if the memory cannot be succesfully allocated.  The `malloc` may cause a system signal to be generated.  Although some C++ libraries implement `new` by calling `malloc`.

There may be a few instances where objects need to be dynamically allocated without invoking their constructors.  In over 20 years, I haven't come across any (not even in the embedded systems arena).

Answer (score 2):

Well, the one thing I can think of, if you're using new you're going to miss realloc if you end up needing it.

Comment: `realloc` doesn't work with non-POD types so using a `vector` is almost always preferred in C++.

Answer (score 2):

My habit is to use `malloc()` for primitive types and C compatible structs, and `new` for everything else.

In the old days this gave better interop with C library code. On Linux, this is still true. On Windows, you need to keep the habit of the library that allocates it frees it.

Answer (score 1):

They key situation in which you must use `malloc` is if the original code ever calls `realloc`.  Of course you can reimplement everything needed, but there isn't that much advantage in doing so.

Comment: `realloc()` is frequently bad news in C++, as non-POD data objects are usually allergic to being moved around arbitrarily.  Use a `vector<>` instead.  It not only does the memory management for you, it does it correctly.

Comment: In the C code that I see, realloc almost always used on byte arrays or pointer arrays. Both are POD.

Answer (score 0):

In general, use `new` except when interfacing with C code.

The key point on this is that what is allocated with `new` must be freed with `delete`, and what is allocated with `malloc` must be freed with `free`.  You cannot allocate with `new` and free with `free()` or vice-versa.  So, about the only time you need `malloc` is when you need to pass data off to some C code that might `free()` or `realloc()` it.