# C++ : Segmentation fault (core dumped) On linux OS

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, allocation, assign

Im triying to compile and execute this small c++ code using g++ 5.1, it's compiled fine, when i execute it on `linux` i get this error message : "`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`".

But the same code run correctly on osx but not on linux :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct node {
 std::string data;
};

int main() {
  struct node * node = (struct node * )
  malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  node->data.assign("string");
  // node->data = "string" --> same issue

  return 0;
}
```

i tried a simple assigne (node->data = "string"), but i got the same problem Any help please !

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++ code? `new` will initialise the string object - `malloc` does not.

Comment: Who keeps teaching stuff like this? Does it not occur to those people that the 80s are over? :/

Comment: To expand on what @EdHeal said:  it's not enough to just allocate sizeof(struct node) bytes and then start using them.  You have to make sure the string object's constructor runs also, so that the node object's private state will be initialized correctly.  In order to do that you need to use the new operator (e.g. node = struct node * node = new node; )

Comment: Btw, have a look at the linked question, it's probably not quite a dupe, but highly related at least.

Comment: `C++` programs are not "scripts".

Comment: @EdHeal and Jermy thank's it's worked now after using new :)

Comment: @Galik so what is called ?

Comment: @AHmédNet Its generally referred to as "code". For example "some code", "this code". "I wrote some code", "I have some code". "A piece of code" etc

Comment: @AHmédNet Scripts are technically different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language ALSO http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/script.htm

Comment: @Galik thank's im gonna changing script by code :)

Comment: And in programming "code" is *never* pluralized using an 's'. You would *never* say "codes". (When people do that it's grammatically incorrect)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't `malloc` a C++ string. You should be using proper `new` and `delete`, at least, so that constructors are invoked. Stop using C in C++.

Ideally you wouldn't even use `new`; just have a normal object with automatic storage duration or, if you desperately need dynamic allocation, `std::make_unique`.

There is no need for manual memory management in 2016.

Comment: `There is no need for manual memory management in 2016.` I guess I can throw away my custom allocators then.. :(

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit : you mean smart pointer taking over manual memory management?

Comment: @GillBates: That doesn't count ;)

Comment: @GillGates: The code which uses your allocators does not use manual memory management. IOW, you took the automation in your own hands on a lower level, but it's still automatic on a higher level.

Answer (score 5):

With C++ forget about `malloc()`.  If you want to allocate an object use `new`:

```
node * n = new node;   // or if your variable should be called node 
                       // you'd need new struct node to disambiguate
```

The problem with `malloc()` is that it just allocates uninitialized memory. It doesn't ensure the C++ semantic of object creation.  So the string inside your node is not initilized to a valid state.  This causes the assignment of this string to be UB.

If you'd really need to use `malloc()` in C++, you'd need to use a [placement new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) afterwards to initialize the object to a valid state ([online demo](http://ideone.com/k3tjCk)).

```
 void *p = malloc(sizeof(node));   // not so a good idea ! 
 node *n2 = new (p)node;           // but ok, it's feasible.
```

Comment: Why does the string has to be initialized since he is replacing what ever its there with "string" ... also how does the new make sure the constructor of string is called?

Comment: @solti That's what `new` does, it allocates memory and calls the constructor.

Comment: @GillBates since string is not constructed ( because constructor not called for string) that is why the segfault?

Comment: @solti Yes, it's undefined behaviour to just pretend the allocated memory is a string object and use it as one

Comment: Note that using placement new requires the programmer to explicitly call the object's destructor too at the end of it's lifetime.

Comment: @GillBates about destruction afeter a placement new you are of course vey wise to remind it.  For AHméd Net: detailed explanation in the link to the placement new article.

Comment: @GillBates I found this link which is similar to our discussion ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995099/malloc-and-constructors

Comment: @AHmédNet you might want to accept anyone of the answers