# My vector works sometimes and othertimes it doesn't

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make my own vector, but i've got the following problem: When I push_back 100 times there's no problem. When I push_back 1000 the program does not work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct Exception {
    static const char* out_of_range;
};

const char* Exception::out_of_range = "[Error]: Out of range";

template < typename T >
struct vector {
    typedef T myType;
public:
    vector() { 
        m_vector = (myType*) malloc ( sizeof( myType ) );
        m_position = 0; 
    }
    template < typename ... Ts >
    vector(myType head, Ts ... tail) {
        m_position = 0;
        m_vector = (myType*) malloc( (sizeof ...( tail ) + 1) * sizeof( myType ) );
        this->push_back(head);
        (this->push_back(tail),...);
    }
    ~vector() { 
        free(m_vector); 
        m_vector = NULL;
    }
    void push_back( myType value ) {
        m_vector[ m_position ] = value;
        ++m_position;
        m_vector = (myType*) realloc(m_vector, m_position * sizeof(myType));
    }
    void pop_back() {
        --m_position;
        m_vector = (myType*)realloc( m_vector, m_position * sizeof (myType) );
    }

    myType at( size_t pos ) {
        try {
            if (pos < m_position) 
                return m_vector[ pos ];
            else throw Exception::out_of_range;
        } catch (const char* e) {
            printf("%s", e);
            return (myType){};
        }
    }

    inline myType& front() { return *m_vector; }
    inline myType& back() { return *(m_vector + size() -1); }
    inline myType* data() { return m_vector; }

    inline myType* begin() { return m_vector; }
    inline myType* end() { return (m_vector + size()); }

    inline myType operator[](size_t pos) { return m_vector[ pos ]; }
    inline size_t size() { return m_position; }
    inline bool empty () { return (begin() == end()? true:false); }

private:
    myType* m_vector;
    size_t m_position;
};
```

Here is my main that use push_back by 100 times:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) v.push_back(i);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) std::cout << v[i];
}
```

And here the hunted code ahah:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) v.push_back(i);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) std::cout << v[i];
}
```

With "doesn't work" I'm trying to say that when I have 100 values inserted by push_back the program show me all the values from 0 to 99... but when I've got 1000 values (I don't know why) the program show only a black screen and nothing more

Comment: Your not following the rule of 3 /5 /0. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: I don't undestand

Comment: I hope myType is just a POD type.

Comment: Nope is only a type-alias for typename T

Comment: What do think happens when you do `m_vector[ m_position ] = value;` *before* resizing the array?

Comment: @EmanuelClur Since `T` is a template parameter, you can't be sure it's not going to be a class! If `T` happens to be a non-*trivially-copyable* class, then your `realloc` calls will be a problem as they don't call move constructors properly. You should use `new` instead.

Comment: "I'm trying to make my own vector" - Why?

Comment: Why are you using variadic templates? You're allowing arbitrary types to be pushed onto the vector that can only be viewed as `myType`, which is breaking lots of language rules already. If you want a polymorphic vector, the first and simplest thing would be `std::vector<std::any>`. If you really can't use that, at least make sure that you stay consistent with stored types and don't break the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Fun fact: `struct` defaults to `public` access, so `typedef T myType;` is `public` whatever your intents.

Comment: @JesperJuhl To be fair, it could be a good exercise. Using a custom vector in real code without a reason is silly, but creating one for practice is not.

Comment: The template class does not implement the `[]` operator overload that's used in the alleged `main()` function. Conclusion: the shown code is fake code, and not the real code.

Comment: This question needs a lot of clarification. 1) Why can't you just use `std::vector`? 2) Do you really want a polymorphic vector? 3) What do you mean by "compile but don't work?" Please describe the desired behavior and the actual behavior.

Comment: @alterigel I'm trying to make a new vector... I cn't use a std::vector for define my vector...

Comment: Not a good idea to catch an exception and then return a bogus object. If you can't handle the exception in a meaningful manner, prefer to let the exception fall through to the caller and let them figure out how they want to proceed.

Comment: Ahhh! More code! Now this is solvable, so I'm going to invest some non-trivial effort and see if I can spot the real problem.

Comment: @EmanuelClure  [Compare and contrast](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0a6b020979a3b5e).  Your version will not work for a vector of `std::string` or any other non-POD types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the first call of

```
void push_back(myType value) {
    m_vector[m_position] = value; // Store into 0
    ++m_position; // set `m_position` to 1
    m_vector = (myType*)realloc(m_vector, m_position * sizeof(myType)); // Allocate more space.
}
```

How much more space is allocated on that last line? `m_position * sizeof(myType)`. This resolves to `1 * sizeof(myType)`. Enough space for 1 `myType`. In other words the same amount of space the program already had. This is not useful.

Let's look at the next `push_back`

```
void push_back(myType value) {
    m_vector[m_position] = value; // Store into 1. There is no 1. Program now broken
    ++m_position; // set `m_position` to 2
    m_vector = (myType*)realloc(m_vector, m_position * sizeof(myType)); // Allocate more space.
}
```

The next `push_back` writes into invalid storage. Program now officially broken and no further point debugging.

How do we fix this?

Let's ignore the fact that `malloc` and family [don't handle complex data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995099/malloc-and-constructors) and `vector` does not observe [the Rules of Three and Five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Those are best handled in other questions. How do we fix this with `realloc`?

```
m_vector = (myType*) realloc(m_vector, (m_position +1) * sizeof(myType));
```

smooths over the immediate rough spot. But this is inefficient as hell. Every addition triggers a realloc. This really, really hurts performance. Aggregate O(1) goes right out the window replaced by O(n), copy every time, plus a potentially very expensive memory allocation.<sup>1</sup>

Worse, what happens when you remove an item? You lose track of how much was in the vector and may find yourself `realloc`ing smaller buffers. Yuck.

To do this right, first add a `m_capacity` member to track how much data can be stored so that we don't have to reallocate if the amount needed is less than the amount required.

Then we test for amount of space and possibly reallocate before trying to store.

```
void push_back( myType value ) {
    if (m_position >= m_capacity)
    { // need to reallocate
        m_capacity *= 2;
        myType * temp = (myType*) realloc(m_vector, m_capacity *sizeof(myType));
        // ask for more than is needed. Reduce number of reallocations needed
        // do not overwrite m_vector. realloc can fail to allocate and then where are you?
        if (temp != NULL) 
        { 
            m_vector = temp;
        }
        else
        {
             // handle error. Probably throw exception. Definitely exit function 
             // before trying to add new element
        }
    }
    m_vector[ m_position ] = value; // now guarantied to have space.
    ++m_position;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>This isn't strictly true. One of the things you'll find is that memory provided often isn't as granular as what you asked for. When the program asks for X bytes, it might get a convenient block of free memory larger than X bytes. You ever noticed that sometimes you can run off the end of a buffer and the program doesn't notice and immediately crash? This extra space is one of the reasons. Quite often `realloc` can take advantage of this and keep using the same allocation over and over, allowing the program to legally see more of it. You can't count on this, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you make me brain it more clean:
    void push_back( myType value ) {
  if( m_position == 0 ) {
   m_vector[ m_position ] = value;
  } else {
   m_vector = (myType*) realloc(m_vector, (m_position+1) * sizeof(myType));
   m_vector[ m_position ] = value;
  }
  m_position++;
 }

Comment: @EmanuelClur confirmed your proposed solution and added a better one.

Comment: Don't you need (e.g.) `m_capacity *= 2;  myType *temp = (myType *) = realloc(m_vector, m_capacity  * sizeof(myType));`?

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the idea behind your code is that m_vector should always be able to hold one more value than it currently does. Your push_back funtion is wrong then, it should realloc for m_position + 1.