# What is the problem with appending arbitrary object to the array?

Tags: c++, xcode, oop

I have a simple program that process strings from a file into arbitrary class Student (provided below) and appends it to self-written container ArraySequence. When error almost always occurs on marked line (marked with *****).

Class Student:

```cpp
class Student {
public:
    int year;
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    Student(int _year, std::string _name, std::string _surname) {
        this->year = _year;
        this->name = _name;
        this->surname = _surname;
    }
    Student(const Student& s) {
        this->year = s.year;
        this->name = s.name;
        this->surname = s.surname;
    }
    Student& operator=(const Student& s) {
        this->year = s.year;
        this->name = s.name;
        this->surname = s.surname;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const Student& s) const {
        if (this->year == s.year && this->name == s.name && this->surname == s.surname)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

main:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::ifstream data("filename");
    std::string buffer;
    ArraySequence<Student>* entities = new ArraySequence<Student>;

    getline(data, buffer, '\n');
    while (buffer.size() != 0) {
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        int len = static_cast<int>(buffer.find(" "));
        std::string surname = buffer.substr(0, len);
        buffer = buffer.substr(len + 1);
        len = static_cast<int>(buffer.find(" "));
        std::string name = buffer.substr(0, len);
        int year = std::stoi(buffer.substr(len + 1));
        Student b(year, name, surname);
        entities->append(b); *****
        getline(data, buffer, '\n');
    }

    std::cout << count << std::endl;
```

Append:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void ArraySequence<T>::append(const T& item) {
    ISequence<T>::length++;
    if (!(ISequence<T>::length - 1)) {
        data = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T));
    }
    else {
        data = (T*)realloc(data, sizeof(T) * ISequence<T>::length);
    }
    *(data + ISequence<T>::length - 1) = item;
}
```

Errors:
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`;
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x3)`;

Sometimes it would just work, but other times it crashes with errors.

I'm using Xcode 11.1

In Thread 1 it says that problem with operator= of Student on the line `c++ this->surname = s.surname;`

What can I do in a situation like this? Any ideas?

Comment: The segfault occurs when calling a method of a class that's not even shown in your question, `ArraySequence`. But the problem can be anywhere in your program. Just because a program crashes at a particular place doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ does not work this way. You need to read stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and [ask]. Unless you show sufficient information that will allow anyone to cut/paste, compile, and reproduce your problem themselves, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: What is `Array`?  And if its purpose is to be a dynamic array, why aren't you using `std::vector` for this purpose?  Also `ArraySequence<Student>* entities = new ArraySequence<Student>;` -- in C++, there is no need for `new` to create objects.  Instead: `ArraySequence<Student> entities;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie because using self-written Array class is a part of this task.

Comment: First, that is not the entire `ArraySequence` class.  Second, `malloc` and `realloc`?  In a C++ program?  Your program is broken from the start, since you are not creating objects with `malloc`, and your `Student` class has `std::string` members.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the entire ```ArraySequence``` is too huge to put here. Yes, ```malloc``` and ```realloc``` because I find them more convenient (possibly mistakenly) than using ```new``` for this purpose.

Comment: Your code is wrong, period, full stop.  Your `Student` class contains `std::string` members, meaning that it needs to be *constructed*, not just memory allocated.  C++ is not just `C` with a few syntax differences.  When you create non-trivial types, they need to be constructed, else the behavior is undefined.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995099/malloc-and-constructors)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand. Is there any way to reallocate memory dynamically in C++ as ```realloc``` does it?

Comment: You will just have to use the `new[]` allocation, copy, `delete[]` deallocation steps.  Also, a better implementation of your `ArraySequence` would overallocate (maybe double the current amount), so that a simple `append` wouldn't automatically invoke a reallocation (a `capacity` member would be introduced)..  Imagine if somewone were to call `append` in a loop of 100 or 1000 items?  You would do the `realloc` 100 or 1000 times?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie in this case, ```Array``` becomes much slower? Or I'm thinking wrong? I get your idea about ```capacity```, thank you!

Comment: That's why the strategy of overallocating is done, so that you're not calling allocation functions every single time.  So it is not necessarily slower or faster, just less calls to the heap allocation functions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and the last question: Isn't overallocating leads to a loss of space?

Comment: It is a tradeoff between space and speed.  Calling the allocator each and every time an item is appended is deemed more costly than giving up some bytes of extra space.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie big thanks to you for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` consists of a non-trivial type (`Student` contains `std::string`, plus non-trivial copy/ assignment and destructor), using `malloc` and `realloc` will not work correctly.

`malloc` and `realloc` do not create viable objects. They only allocate memory. Your program likely crashes due to these invalid `Student` objects.

The easiest solution is to rewrite `ArraySequence<T>::append` to only use `new[]` and `delete[]`, not `malloc` and `realloc`.

Note: `malloc` can be used when using [placement-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new), but you were not using `malloc` for this purpose.