# Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) for template with double but not int

Tags: c++, templates

I tried to make a dynamic array that adds elements at the beginning of the array. It works just fine with int, but when i try double, it gives me the error Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005). Debugging it works perfectly and all are in range, but when i run it crashes.

This is the header:

```
#define DYNAMICARRAY_H
#include <cstddef>

template <class T>
class DynamicArray
{
    public:
        DynamicArray();
        DynamicArray(size_t);
        DynamicArray(const DynamicArray&);
        virtual ~DynamicArray();

        DynamicArray& operator=(const DynamicArray&);
        T &operator[] (size_t);

        void add(T element);
        size_t getCapacity();
        size_t getLength();
        bool isEmpty();
        void print();
        void resizeArr();

    protected:

    private:
        T *arr;
        size_t capacity;
        size_t length;
};
#endif // DYNAMICARRAY_H
```

This is the .cpp

```
#include "DynamicArray.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
DynamicArray<T>::DynamicArray()
{
    length = 0;
    capacity = 1;
    arr = (T*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(arr));
    if(!arr){
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

}

template <class T>
DynamicArray<T>::DynamicArray(size_t newSize)
{
    length = 0;
    capacity = newSize;
    arr = (T*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(arr));
    if(!arr){
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
}

template <class T>
DynamicArray<T>::~DynamicArray()
{
    delete[] arr;
    delete arr;
    delete &capacity;
    delete &length;
}

template <class T>
DynamicArray<T>::DynamicArray(const DynamicArray& other)
{
    length = other.length;
    capacity = other.capacity;
    arr = (T*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(arr));
    if(!arr){
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++){
        arr[i] = other.arr[i];
    }

}

template <class T>
DynamicArray<T>& DynamicArray<T>::operator=(const DynamicArray& rhs)
{
    if (this == &rhs){
        return *this;
    }

    delete[] arr;

    length = rhs.length;
    capacity = rhs.capacity;
    arr = (T*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(arr));
    if(!arr){
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++){
        arr[i] = rhs.arr[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

template <class T>
size_t DynamicArray<T>::getLength()
{
    return length;
}

template <class T>
size_t DynamicArray<T>::getCapacity()
{
    return capacity;
}

template <class T>
bool DynamicArray<T>::isEmpty(){
    return length == 0;
}

template <class T>
T &DynamicArray<T>::operator[] (size_t index)
{
    if(index >= length){
        std::cout << "Array index out of bounds" << "\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    return arr[index];
}

template <class T>
void DynamicArray<T>::add(T element)
{
    if(length >= capacity){
        resizeArr();
    }
    if(!isEmpty()){
        for(size_t i = length; i > 0; i--){
            arr[i] = arr[i-1];
        }
    }

    arr[0] = element;
    length ++;

}

template <class T>
void DynamicArray<T>::print()
{
    if(length == 0){
        std::cout << "The array is empty!";
    }
    else{
        for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++){
            std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

template <class T>
void DynamicArray<T>::resizeArr(){
    size_t newCapacity = capacity * 2;
    T *arr2 = (T*)realloc(arr, newCapacity * sizeof(arr));

    if(!arr2){
        std::cout << "Bad memory allocation";
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    arr = arr2;
    capacity = newCapacity;
}

template class DynamicArray<double>;
template class DynamicArray<int>;
```

And the main

```
#include "DynamicArray.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));


    DynamicArray<int> d(5);
    int randomInt;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < d.getCapacity(); i++){
        randomInt = rand()% 100;
        d.add(randomInt);
    }

    d.print();


    d.add(5);
    d.add(55);
    d.add(3);
    d.add(33);
    d.add(37);

    d.print();

    delete &d;

    cout << "\n\n";

    DynamicArray<double> d2(5);

    double randomDouble;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < d2.getCapacity() - 3; i++){
        //randomDouble = (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX);
        randomDouble = 0.5f;
        d2.add(randomDouble);
        d2.print();
    }

    d2.print();

    return 0;
}
```

It crashes at the second for in the main, I've tried to make sure everything it set correctly, but still won't work:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < d2.getCapacity() - 3; i++){
        //randomDouble = (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX);
        randomDouble = 0.5f;
        d2.add(randomDouble);
        d2.print();
    }
```

Comment: Don't `delete` pointer to local variables, nor member of a class.

Comment: You combine `malloc` with `delete`. Sounds like a bad idea. Use the C++ `new` operator. And maybe also look into smart pointers...

Comment: Seems like [a similar homework assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904203/what-is-the-problem-with-appending-arbitrary-object-to-the-array), with the exact same issues.

Comment: Also, a `DynamicArray<std::string>` will fail miserably due to using `malloc` and `free` instead of `new[]` and `delete[]`.  Also, the assignment operator is flawed.  If `malloc` returns NULL, you have a zombie object floating around the code that is invalid to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = (T*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(arr));
```

`sizeof(arr)` is the same as `sizeof(T*)` which isn't what you want, I suppose.
This should rather be `sizeof(*arr)` or `sizeof(T)`.

---

Apart from that, don't mix `malloc/delete` or `new/free`, as others already pointed out.

If you're doing C, use `malloc/free`, and if you're in C++ use `new/delete`.

Using `new` would change the above to

```
arr = new T[capacity];
```

avoiding the whole sizing altogether.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it was the problem of mixing together the malloc/ delete and new/free. It works now! :D

Comment: There are more problems in the code beyond mixing `malloc/delete`. @eerorika already pointed out the deletes of non-allocated elements, or the double delete of `arr`.

Comment: @DonVladster be warned: your code [has undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9169774/10957435). That means it can appear to work, but really not. Please see [eerorika's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58920376/10957435).

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> arr = (T*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(arr));
>
> delete[] arr;
> delete arr;
> delete &capacity;
> delete &length;
>
> delete &d;
> ```

You pass pointers to `delete[]` and `delete` that were not returned from `new[]` or `new` respectively. Behaviour of the program is undefined. Relevant language rule:

> [expr.delete]
>
> ... In a single-object delete expression, the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject representing a base class of such an object. If not, the behavior is undefined. In an array delete expression, the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value or a pointer value that resulted from a previous array new-expression.
>   If not, the behavior is undefined. ...

Every `delete` expression of your program violate this rule.

To fix this, you must consistently use `free` on memory allocated with `malloc`, `realloc` or `strdup`, and use `delete` with pointers allocated with `new`, `delete[]` with pointers allocated with `new[]`, absolutely no deallocation functions with pointers to non-dynamic objects such as member variables or objects with automatic or static storage duration, (or invalid pointers).

Comment: Also `delete &d;` wherrrrg

Comment: Is the issue in the copy constructor, or should i not use `delete[] arr` at all?
i tried `free(arr)` but it still didnt work

Comment: @DonVladster Your program may have more bugs than this one.

Comment: @eerorika thanks! It was a problem of using malloc/delete and the other wrong! I will review the code for other issues

Comment: *To fix this, you must consistently use free on memory allocated with malloc* -- The issue with this is if a `std::string` or basically any non-trivial type were to be used for `T`.  Then `malloc` and `free` will cause other issues.